# What is the probability of finding all of the red marbles given D draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm having trouble intuiting how to do this...

Suppose I have a jar of M marbles, of which R are red.  What is the probability of finding all R red marbles given D (non-replaced) draws?

Comment: Have you heard about the [hypergeometric distribution](http://www.statisticshowto.com/hypergeometric-distribution-examples/)?

Comment: @Arthur Could you please mention how is it solved using Hypergeometric distribution?

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by Arthur in a comment, using hypergeometric distributions solves it.

$ P(x) =  \frac{M-R \choose D-R}{M \choose D} $

Intuitively, this frames the problem as finding the probability of drawing the correct amount of non-red marbles (i.e., $D-R$)

$P(x) = \frac{Number\ of\ desired\ outcomes}{Total\ number\ of\ possible\ outcomes} = \frac{Number\ of\ ways\ to\ draw\ D-R\ non-red\ marbles}{Number\ of\ ways\ to\ draw\ from\ all\ marbles} = \frac{M-R \choose D-R}{M \choose D}$